# [i]makeidx together with scrlayer-scrpage and tabbing in header leads to 'Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{theindex}' error

Tags: indexing, scrlayer-scrpage, tabbing, makeidx

I tried to add an index to one of my documents. This however failed, as the following MWI does as well. The cryptic error message is:

```
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{theindex}
```

The MWI:

```
\documentclass{scrreport}

\RequirePackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\cohead[
                {
                \begin{tabbing}
                               plain      \= header content
                \end{tabbing}
                }
                ]
                {
                               header content
                }

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
                
Test \index{indexEntry}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

The problem seems to be the `tabbing` environment in the plain-style entry of the `\cohead` macro.

Replacing the `tabbing` environment with a `tabular` environment removed the error - I am however still wondering what the actual problem is.

Additionally it seems replacing `\usepackage{makeidx}` with `\usepackage{imakeidx}` seems to remove the error for this MWI - not however for my full document.

If anyone has a clue, as to what I did wrong here - please let me know.

Thanks,

Johannes

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for `tabbing` in the header?

Comment: The reason for the `tabbing` environment in the header is that several lines of information should be provided in an aligned way. In above MWI I tried to reduce it to the absolute minimun required to reproduce the error - which actually makes this tabbing rather senseless now. Sorry, if I was unclear about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First, an analysis of the problem

The `theindex` environment (which is inserted by `\printindex`) changes the definition of `\item` to do something else, which basically breaks all lists. In LaTeX, more things are lists than you may think, including `tabbing`. Now, when a page ends while that changed definition is in effect, it also affects the header and footer (which are typeset only then), which leads to the error. A somewhat more minimal example producing the error would be

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\cohead{%
  \begin{tabbing}
    one \= two
  \end{tabbing}%
}

\begin{document}
                
Hello World!
\let\item\relax

\end{document}
```

or even

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
                
\let\item\relax
\begin{tabbing}
  Hello World!
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

### What to do about it

Now, we could carefully restore the original meaning of `\item` in the header and get rid of the error. However, I would still advise against this, as the `tabbing` environment does not play nice with the alignment of the different header parts even then. (Remove `\let\item\relax` from the first example above. Is the header set by `\cohead` in the center?)

Instead, it seems to me that you really want a table.

```latex
\documentclass[
    headlines=2,
  ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{showframe}

\lohead*{left text for alignment and such}
\rohead*{right text for alignment and such}
\cohead*{%
  \strut\smash{%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{ l l }
      one & two \\
      three & four \\
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
                
Test\index{indexEntry}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Some notes on this:

- `showframe` is just so we can see the type area.
- Use `headlines=2` to make the header high enough for two lines of text.
- Use `tabular`'s optional argument to specify the vertical alignment with the rest of the header (`[b]` for bottom alignment).
- `scrlayer-scrpage` puts each of the different parts of the header inside a `\parbox`, which vertically centers its content with surrounding one by default (which would make the `[b]` from before useless). For some reason, no option is provided to change this. In order to get around this without getting into the internals of the package, I used the following trick: I removed the height of the table using `\smash` and added a `\strut` (a zero-width rule). That is, the content of the `\cohead` now has the width of the `tabular` and the height of the `\strut`, which leads to the desired alignment.

  Note that this also means that LaTeX can't warn you anymore if your header gets too high (because we remove that height). You would not get a warning even without `headlines=2`. You will have to check the height yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what `tabbing` is doing in that position (it makes LaTeX issue a warning about the head height).

You can fix the issue by specifying that you set the first page style in the index to the one used by `scrlayer-scrpage`.

```latex
\documentclass{scrreport}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\cohead[%
  \begin{tabbing}
  plain \= header content
  \end{tabbing}%
]{%
  header content%
}


\makeindex
\indexsetup{firstpagestyle=plain.scrheadings}

\begin{document}

\chapter{whatever}

Test\index{indexEntry}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

However, the problem with the head height remains to be solved.

```latex
Package scrlayer-scrpage Warning: \headheight to low.
(scrlayer-scrpage)                At least 58.8pt needed,
(scrlayer-scrpage)                but only 17.0pt found.
(scrlayer-scrpage)                I'll enlarge \headheight, for further
(scrlayer-scrpage)                processing, but you should do this yourself,
(scrlayer-scrpage)                e.g., setting typearea's option
(scrlayer-scrpage)                `headheight=58.8pt'.
(scrlayer-scrpage)                I'll also decrease \topmargin on input line 26.
```